# Process Flow Diagams - Chemical Engineering

Tags: mac, software-recommendation

Can anyone suggest software for making Process Flow diagrams on Mac OS alike the ones available for Windows like Ansys?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Omnigraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle) for any diagrams. It's easy to use and highly compatible with OS X frameworks. It also has quite large database of additional stencils [here](https://stenciltown.omnigroup.com) and [here](https://www.graffletopia.com). Omnigraffle 6 is 99$ and Pro version is 199$.

Answer (score 0):

Omnigraffle is certainly great.  If you want to try a free application I would suggest Apache OpenOffice "Draw" for diagramming:

https://www.openoffice.org/